# Can my username and profile picture be my company?

Tags: discussion, spam, display-names, terms-of-service, self-promotion

Let's assume I submit high-quality and unbiased answers, that contain no marketing ploys, no suggestions and no references to my company: they will be as unbiased as any other contributor's. Most of the time, these answers won't even be directly related to the product the company sells (e.g. a VPN company answering questions about UX testing).

The T&Cs state:

> Users that ... use deceptive means to generate revenue or traffic ... will be suspended.

Now, there's obviously some intent for brand awareness going on here: the hope is people will see the logo / company name and gain trust for it. Also if there's a link to the company in my profile, some traffic might also come from it.

If the answers are helpful, is it OK for the username and logo to be commercial?

Example:

- Username: "Google".
- Profile picture: "The Google G"

Anti-example (mine wouldn't be like this):

- Username: "FREE C++ COURSES!!!"
- Profile picture: "C++ 4 FREE"

Comment: I've also seen people hyphenate the company they are representing in their username. There's plenty of "Firstname Lastname - MSFT" users on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I'm aware, some of the sites on the SE network serve as semi-official support portals for some products and as such representatives offer answers accordingly.

As long as your answers are unbiased and answer the question without overtly or unnecessarily pushing your product, then you should be ok.

> You can solve this by configuring x, y, and z in GoGoGadget

is better than seeking out commercial opportunities by only answering if there's money to be made

> You can solve this by getting the ProToolkit plugin from our website (we accept Paypal/Visa/Bitcoin)

The inference is helping customers as opposed to helping yourself (or your business).

Answer (score 6):

I don't see a problem with using your company name and logo, as long as you own the legal rights to use them. Probably your answers will be "valued less" because of it. That is something I noticed from my own experience. I tend to value answers written by "individuals" better, even if they are of similar quality.

Something you should be extra careful about is when you are answering questions regarding your product. In those cases state very clearly, preferably at the top of your answer, that you have a (business) interest there, and that you own/are part of company X which produces software package Y.

Other then that it boils far more down to the way in which you write. Is a post an objective answer to a certain question, or is it a glorious recommendation for your own product, in disguise.